# Permission denied when I want to push something to my remote git

Tags: github

**update:** I added a ssh connection , now I can push to all 3 repos xD
Thank you guys!

I want to push data to my other git account.

origin = remote address

But it displays me, that my other user account has no permission.
What does this user has to to with my other account xD

Am I somehow logged in?

Why can I push it to my third account without any problem?

```
$ git push origin master
remote: Permission to myshareplace/synth.git denied to xxx.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: It seems you are using the wrong config check configuration through this. git config --list --show-origin

Comment: shows the user.name and user.email of my third account it shows one file: .git/config with remote .origin.url= path to my wanted push directory

Comment: Did you try to push with the ssh://git URL?

Comment: I have not tried this. what is this? xD

Comment: Change your repo URL HTTPS to ssh.

Comment: ok I will try :D

Comment: wow it worked... it was a bit *******  to configure everything but now I can push to all my 3 repositories xD

Comment: :) great, happy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please, open your
`Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Credential Manager`
and then in `Generic Credentials` find `git:https://github.com`
then remove current account or change it

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following command and it will ask to enter the account again:

```
git remote set-url origin <URL-TO-REPOSITORY>
```

After:

```
git push origin master
```

If it keeps giving the same error, try this second method:

```
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true
```

After:

```
git push origin master
```

;)

Comment: Why would you use `git config --global credential.useHttpPath true` here?